# python-ldap stronger authentication

Tags: python, python-ldap

I'm trying to make a search in our AD with python-ldap.

When I try to make the:

```
connect.simple_bind_s('ldap_login', 'ldap_password')
```

I am getting the error:

> ldap.STRONG_AUTH_REQUIRED: {'msgtype': 97, 'msgid': 1, 'result': 8,
> 'desc': 'Strong(er) authentication required', 'ctrls': [], 'info':
> '00002028: LdapErr: DSID-0C090276, comment: The server requires binds
> to turn on integrity checking if SSL\TLS are not already active on
> the connection, data 0, v2580'}

I am searching since a day and can't find anything serious about this.

I would be very thankfull if anyone could tell me how to authenticate with a stronger authentication. I found something with certificates but this also was only a question and had no answer since ever.

So yeah a little example or a link to a documentation were it's shown how to do this would be great.

Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using ldap3 for AD.

```
from ldap3 import Server, Connection, SUBTREE, ALL
def auth(user_id, password):
        try:
            server = Server('domain.name', get_info = None)
            conn = Connection(server, client_strategy = 'ASYNC', user = user_id,
                              password = password,
                              check_names = False,
                              raise_exceptions = False)

            status = conn.bind()
            conn.unbind()
        except:
            status = False
        return status
```

Comment: yep thanks somehow ran over the ldap3 and forgot to update my question. Works a lot better with this module!

Answer (score 1):

This error (at least in my case) was due to an AD setup that had been changed to require SSL.  The specific change you'll need to make when connecting will be dependent on how AD is set up on your network, but when creating the Server object you'll likely need to use the "use_ssl" option.  You may have to make other adjustments, such as setting TLS with the "tls" option, though in my case adding "use_ssl=True" was the only change I needed to make.

For example, here's the connection code I used, with the additional parameter in the first line.

```
server_instance = Server(server_name, get_info=ALL, use_ssl=True)
connection = Connection(server_instance, user=user_name, password=password, check_names=True, auto_bind=True)

if not connection.bind():
    print(f'ERROR:  Failed to connect:  {connection.result}')
```